# Twilio: End conference if only one participant left

Tags: twilio

I am using Twilio Conference verb to create conference between our application users.
Use case: When two users (caller and callee) are on a call and want to add third participant in call. I am doing this using participant APIs. But when third participant is added and its in ringing state and 1st two participants disconnect, then 3rd participant still goes in ringing state. I want to end the conference when there is only one participant left.

I can do this by checking no. of participants everytime any event happen, but in this case I dont get call sid of 3rd participant when I fetch participants of conference because its in ringing state. If call is received by 3rd participant then it appears in fetch API.

How can I get call sid of participant which is in ringing state? or is there any other wau to achieve this

(Note: I cannot use endConferenceOnExit because of use case)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion. You won't be able to stop the call once it starts ringing. However, what you can do is let the third participant ring, let them join the conference, when the third participant joins the conference, always check the number of conference participants. If the number of participants is less than 3 then end the conference. To do this, setup a webhook for "participant join" to monitor for the third participant. Don't forget you can include a url variable to track which participant is causing the webhook: "https://yourwebhookendpoint.com/conferenceevent/participantjoin?user=thirdparty". The user=thirdparty is how your webhook will know which business rules to process when it receives a "participant join" event.

I am providing this general solution since you seem pretty familiar with the API.

Comment: Problem is user phone keeps ringing and when they answer a call there is no other party. I dont think its a good experience

Comment: This is typical in a call center environment. Agents call this "dead-air" calls aka inbound disconnects. Is ringing once or twice really that different than ringing five or six times? Given that phone systems take a few seconds to respond you could at best get it down to ringing once or twice. Also, to clarify something I wrote, if the phone was ringing you can use Twilio to update the status to Completed. This would stop the phone from ringing. My assumption was that your agent was answering within a few rings - not like 10 rings. Stopping the call within a few rings isn't likely possible.